# Unable to get past '403 - forbidden' Python Webscraping - Tried Changing Header

Tags: python

I'm trying to webscrape a website, and although I'm able to get access to the website on my computer using Chrome, not matter what I'm trying in python, I keep getting status code 403 - forbidden. I've already tried messing around with the user agent, along with various combinations of network headers in my request. But I still keep getting this issue.

```
import requests
headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
         'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
         'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
         'Referer': 'https://duckduckgo.com/',
         'TE':'trailers',
         'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
         'USER-AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
         'X-Real-Ip': '[insert IP]',
         'X-Http-Proto': 'HTTP/1.1',
        'Host': 'curseforge.com'}

url = 'https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks?page=2'
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(req.status_code)
```

Output: 403

I'm at the point now where I'd just like to open a chrome browser, and pull from the inspect element from chrome itself...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try giving time for the requests before printing it. Something like `time.sleep(random.randint(3,5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you are in no luck here. Since `https://www.curseforge.com` is protected by Cloudfare, I tried to run your script **with** and **without** the [cloudfare-scrap](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) library.

But both times I get `Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.`, since Cloudfare and reCAPTCHA do an amazing job at preventing DDoS and scrapers like yours, they are difficult to bypass. But I do have came up with a few solutions to hack through it although be aware that none of these is perfect

1. you can break the google reCAPTCHA, more datails here [Blackhat conference 2016](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-16/materials/asia-16-Sivakorn-Im-Not-a-Human-Breaking-the-Google-reCAPTCHA.pdf),
2. you can extract the the temporary cookies that the reCAPTCHA gives you when you passed it, and inject it in your request every time. But be aware of this method as too many requests to the same page will make your host suspicious and it may revoke your cookies and you will have to refresh it again.
3. Lastly you can try alternate approach and use selenium to open a browser driver for manual reCAPTCHA input.